# android-clearing backstack generates NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition, fragment-backstack

I have 4 fragments in my app : `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. first of all, one instance of fragment A is added to the  activity, without adding to backstack. then the user can dynamically navigate to indefinite number of fragments. suppose this scenario:

```
            addToBackstack    addToBackstack    addToBackstack    addToBackstack
========> A ==============> B ==============> D ==============> D ==============> C
```

**some of these transitions include shared elements as well**, for example from B to D:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.setReorderingAllowed(true)
.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, D.newInstance(bundle), TAG)
.addSharedElement(view, name)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```

now I need to take user from last fragment directly to the first fragment (A). so I have tried:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

**which works well, but not always**. sometimes (I have not been able to find the exact scenarios which definitely result in exception) it crashes the app with the following logs:

```
2021-07-11 00:53:45.623 14155-14155/app.android.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.android.xxx, PID: 14155
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.captureInSharedElements(FragmentTransition.java:924)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.configureSharedElementsReordered(FragmentTransition.java:634)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsReordered(FragmentTransition.java:252)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:152)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2005)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

what is causing this `NullPointerException` and how to solve the issue?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to [Fragment 1.3.5](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.5), which fixes this exact issue (AppCompat 1.3.0 depends only on Fragment 1.3.4, so you wouldn't have this fix by default):

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.5"
```